# Branch name check before merging

Tags: git, github

I want to set up specific branch name convention for my repo.
Lets say prefix like this : `TEST-XXXX` for every branch which will be pushed and merged into the master.  And in case of name which is not finding this prefix i would like to block this merge.

I got regular expression like this:  `^TEST-[0-9]{4}:`

I know that git uses fnmatch convention.
But the question is where and how to use it on github page?

I've already tried under *Branch protection rules*  and *Webhooks*.

Didn't work. Any ideas how to solve this ?

Comment: Requiring pull requests might be a more conventional strategy than blocking merges outright. You could then use hooks to do the check. This question is too broad, though. Please see [ask].

Comment: You suggestion is to require PR and require approvals?  
And then use webhook?

Answer (score 0):

To set up a branch naming convention for your Git repository, you can use a pre-commit hook like this:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Check the branch name
branch_name=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
if ! [[ $branch_name =~ ^TEST-.+$ ]]; then
    # Reject the commit if the branch name doesn't match the pattern
    echo "Error: Branch name must start with 'TEST-'"
    exit 1
fi
```

Once you have created this script, you can save it as `pre-commit` in the `.git/hooks` directory of your repository. This will make it a pre-commit hook that is run automatically before each commit.

Comment: An important caveat with this is that this hook will only be enforced *on that copy of the repository*; anyone else cloning the repository won't have the hook, and can commit to whatever local branches they want.